# How to access the name of a list before mapping it?

Tags: r, mapping, purrr

I am trying to split a data frame into smaller data frames and map them to certain function if they meet the naming condition of the function.I tried many ways with purrr `map` to split directly using map_if but was not lucky so I now work with `split` and `lapply`

So I will write the code where I am stuck wit now.

```
x <- split(mtcars , mtcars$cyl)

lapply(x, function(x){
  print(names(x))
  })
```

what I am expected to get is :

```
4
6
8
```

what I get is

```
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
$`4`
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

$`6`
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

$`8`
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

It appears that it enters the item directly with no way to extract the item parent name from within apply.

Any recommendations of how would you do that will be helpful?

### Update

here is what I want to do in dummy code

```
x <- split(mtcars , mtcars$cyl)

lapply(x, function(x){
  if(names(x) == 4){
somefunction(x)
}
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Lapply goes through each element of the list and then applies the function, this means that `names` gets applied to an individual data frame and therefore outputs the column names.

But my question would be, why access the names at all? In this case the names correspond to the column "cyl" anyway so you could make your function simply depend on the value of that column.

Comment: check the update, please. I want to pass to another function based on this category name. Not all items will be passed to the same function.

Comment: @Omar113 but why can't you pass the function based on the column value which is identical to the df name? All rows in cyl of x$'4' will be 4 so testing for that will be easier than accessing the data frame name.

Comment: should I do that within the apply function it-self or there is no need to split  then lapply and it's better to loop?

Comment: @Omar113 this really depends on your data set, the reason you want to split and the functions you want to apply. You need to add more information. Because if you only wanted to create a new column with a different function based on the 'cyl' value in the example, why even split? Why not use conditional functions in the big df? You have to be more specific in your problem and data set.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix for OP's approach:

```
somefunction <- function(df) dplyr::summarise_all(df, mean)

some_naming_condition <- function(group) group == "4"

lapply(
  names(x),
  function(name) {
    if (some_naming_condition(name)) {
      somefunction(x[[name]])
    } else {
      x[[name]]
    }
  }
)
#> [[1]]
#>        mpg cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec        vs
#> 1 26.66364   4 105.1364 82.63636 4.070909 2.285727 19.13727 0.9090909
#>          am     gear     carb
#> 1 0.7272727 4.090909 1.545455
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> ...
```

Or equivalently:

```
Map(function(name, sub_df) {
  if (some_naming_condition(name)) {
    somefunction(sub_df)
  } else {
    sub_df
  }
}, names(x), x)
```

A different suggested approach:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  nest(-cyl) %>% 
  mutate(data = modify_at(data, which(some_naming_condition(cyl)), 
                          somefunction)) %>% 
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 22 x 11
#>      cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6  21    160  110    3.9   2.62  16.5 0     1      4     4   
#>  2     6  21    160  110    3.9   2.88  17.0 0     1      4     4   
#>  3     6  21.4  258  110    3.08  3.22  19.4 1     0      3     1   
#>  4     6  18.1  225  105    2.76  3.46  20.2 1     0      3     1   
#>  5     6  19.2  168. 123    3.92  3.44  18.3 1     0      4     4   
#>  6     6  17.8  168. 123    3.92  3.44  18.9 1     0      4     4   
#>  7     6  19.7  145  175    3.62  2.77  15.5 0     1      5     6   
#>  8     4  26.7  105.  82.6  4.07  2.29  19.1 0.909 0.727  4.09  1.55
#>  9     8  18.7  360  175    3.15  3.44  17.0 0     0      3     2   
#> 10     8  14.3  360  245    3.21  3.57  15.8 0     0      3     4   
#> # … with 12 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `group_by` and `group_split` can work. Here's an example using `summary` as an arbitrary function to apply to the subset with cylindars == 6.

```
cyl_groups <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)
cyl_groups %>% group_split %>% map_if(group_keys(cyl_groups) == 6, summary)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 11 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  2  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  3  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#>  4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
#>  5  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
#>  6  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
#>  7  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
#>  8  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
#>  9  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
#> 10  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
#> 11  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>       mpg             cyl         disp             hp       
#>  Min.   :17.80   Min.   :6   Min.   :145.0   Min.   :105.0  
#>  1st Qu.:18.65   1st Qu.:6   1st Qu.:160.0   1st Qu.:110.0  
#>  Median :19.70   Median :6   Median :167.6   Median :110.0  
#>  Mean   :19.74   Mean   :6   Mean   :183.3   Mean   :122.3  
#>  3rd Qu.:21.00   3rd Qu.:6   3rd Qu.:196.3   3rd Qu.:123.0  
#>  Max.   :21.40   Max.   :6   Max.   :258.0   Max.   :175.0  
#>       drat             wt             qsec             vs        
#>  Min.   :2.760   Min.   :2.620   Min.   :15.50   Min.   :0.0000  
#>  1st Qu.:3.350   1st Qu.:2.822   1st Qu.:16.74   1st Qu.:0.0000  
#>  Median :3.900   Median :3.215   Median :18.30   Median :1.0000  
#>  Mean   :3.586   Mean   :3.117   Mean   :17.98   Mean   :0.5714  
#>  3rd Qu.:3.910   3rd Qu.:3.440   3rd Qu.:19.17   3rd Qu.:1.0000  
#>  Max.   :3.920   Max.   :3.460   Max.   :20.22   Max.   :1.0000  
#>        am              gear            carb      
#>  Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :3.000   Min.   :1.000  
#>  1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:3.500   1st Qu.:2.500  
#>  Median :0.0000   Median :4.000   Median :4.000  
#>  Mean   :0.4286   Mean   :3.857   Mean   :3.429  
#>  3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:4.000   3rd Qu.:4.000  
#>  Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :5.000   Max.   :6.000  
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 14 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  2  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  3  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
#>  4  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
#>  5  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
#>  6  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
#>  7  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
#>  9  15.5     8  318    150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2
#> 10  15.2     8  304    150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2
#> 11  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
#> 12  19.2     8  400    175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2
#> 13  15.8     8  351    264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
#> 14  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

If you only want to keep the tibbles matching your condition, an alternative is

```
mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% keep(names(.) == 6) %>% map(somefunction())
```